# Flatten two arrays having corresponding values using mapping data flow in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to data flows in adf. I have a set of json files in a folder which i would like to parse and flatten two arrays into a csv.
The json structure is as follows:
[image]

I would like to flatten the timestamps and values arrays. Each timestamp in Timestamps array has the corresponding value in the Values array. i.e, value at Timestamps[i] is Values[i]. The output should have a row for each timestamp and corresponding value for a particular label.

[image]

Can anyone please help me in achieving this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the correlation between 2 arrays use mapIndex function and merge the arrays together. Then you will use a flatten to get it into relational form.

mapIndex(Timestamps, @(
Timestamp = #item, Value = Values[#index]))

Answer (score 0):

In your data flow, add 2 Flatten transformations and point to the Timestamps and Values arrays in the unroll property in each transformation.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried that and it won't work that way. When i flatten the timestamps first, timestamp in each row will have corresponding array of values. Later if i flatten the values array then incorrect data will be created because each timestamp will originally have only one value associated with it. but when we do this, for each timestamp row, instead of one row being created, it will create length(Values) number of rows which is wrong.

Comment: Got it. You can associate the values from the 2 arrays using the mapIndex technique that Kiran mentions in the other answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#mapindex  https://kromerbigdata.com/2021/01/06/transforming-arrays-in-azure-data-factory-and-azure-synapse-data-flows/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather too late for an answer but I came across this when I was struggling to get the example working. Taking what Kiran wrote and expanding on it, I've written it up as a full end-to-end blog post which is here; it might save others time in future

https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/consuming-informatica-api-data-with-data-factory-and-data-flows-a3220f6190d3

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with Azure Synapse Analytics, serverless SQL pools which supports `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE( m.value, '$.Id' ) Id,
    JSON_VALUE( m.value, '$.Label' ) Label,
    t.value AS ts,
    v.value AS v
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://somestorage.dfs.core.windows.net/datalake/raw/json/metrics.json',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        FIELDQUOTE = '0x0b',
        FIELDTERMINATOR ='0x0b',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0b'
    )
    WITH (
        jsonContent varchar(MAX)
    ) AS [result]
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( jsonContent, '$.MetricDataResults' ) m
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( m.value, '$.Timestamps' ) t
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( m.value, '$.Values' ) v
WHERE t.[key] = v.[key];
```

My results:
[image]

It's a valid alternative approach with a pay as you go service.